# Can't add variable to table

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

So, I'm trying to add a variable (string) to another variable (table). My code looks like this:

```
tableName = '123456789'
testVariable = 'test'
c.execute('INSERT INTO ' + tableName + ' (testColumn) VALUES (' + testVariable + ')')
conn.commit()
```

But for some reason, it's giving me this error

```
    c.execute('INSERT INTO ' + tableName + ' (testColumn) VALUES (' + testVariable + ')')
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "123456789": syntax error
```

What do I do?

Comment: you missed  quote around string  ..in sql command

Comment: You're missing your place holders, you have to use ? then the header you want to insert into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to fix it myself. I had to add single quotes to the start and end of the variables, and then use this: `c.execute("INSERT INTO {} (testColumn) VALUES ({})".format(tableName, testVariable))`

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

```py
c.execute("INSERT INTO ? (testColumn) VALUES (?)", (tableName, testVariable))
```

Comment: It now gives me this error: 

`sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error`

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
c.execute('''INSERT INTO 123456789(testColumn) VALUES(?)''', (testVariable))
```